# How to open chrome webdriver with python selenium package , signed into default user?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I want to use chrome webdriver as a logged in chrome user, it normally starts as a plain chrome instance without any cookies and  not logged in to google.
a similar question in the context of java could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420975/selenium-opens-up-chrome-not-signed-into-chrome-account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python:

```
chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/location/to/chrome/profile")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path='/location/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: for the chrome profile path, do not include the /Default at the end.